# Time Period Check

Tags: c#

I want to check if a given period of time(HH:MM) is within the other one and return true else it shall return false

I have tried this equation

```
 (StartTime_1 <= EndTime_2 && StartTime_2 < EndTime_1)    || 
 (StartTime_1 < StartTime_2 && EndTime_2 <= EndTime_1)
```

But it seems to measure overlapping rather than any thing, what i want is like this,
For example Start_1 is 08:00 AM and End_1 is 10:00 PM, any time that comes between these two it shall return true and any other like (from 09 PM to 08 AM) it shall return false.

Comment: `is within the other one`, do you mean completely contained within, or any over-lapping?

Comment: what is the type of your data ? `DateTime` ?

Comment: I suggest you to convert to `Int32` and add 24H to EndTime_X is it is lower than StartTime ...

Comment: So you want to ignore dates and only check on time?

Comment: Yes, i want to ignore the date and check time only

Comment: Give yourself a favor and give https://github.com/Giannoudis/TimePeriodLibrary a try.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of possible cases.
[image]

To check if they overlap at any point in time, you need to check if the end of the test time period start is before time period 1 end, and if the test time end is after period 1 start.

If you have a different description of overlap, you'll have to expand by referencing which lines in the image should be considered in or out.

Comment: There are many more cases where the time periods share endpoints, but I do not show them here because the image gets ugly.

Answer (score 0):

Its hard to tell from your variable names, but it looks like you almost have it right. To test for true containment, you just need to always use "and" (`&&`):

```
DateTime AllowedStart;
DateTime AllowedEnd;

DateTime ActualStart;
DateTime ActualEnd;

//Obviously you should populate those before this check!
if (ActualStart > AllowedStart && //Check the start time
    ActualStart < AllowedEnd && //Technically not necessary if ActualEnd > ActualStart
    ActualEnd < AllowedEnd &&  //Check the end time
    ActualEnd > AllowedStart) //Technically not necessary if ActualEnd > ActualStart
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
(StartTime_2 >= StartTime_1 && EndTime_2 <= EndTime_1) && (StartTime_1 < EndTime_1) && (StartTime_2 < EndTime_2)
```

I would think this should do what you're looking for

Answer (score 0):

With this method, I can check if a period (start2 to end2) is contained in another (start1 to end1)

```
public static Boolean IsContained(DateTime start1, DateTime end1, DateTime start2, DateTime end2)
{
    // convert all DateTime to Int
    Int32 start1_int = start1.Hour * 60 + start1.Minute;
    Int32 end1_int = end1.Hour * 60 + end1.Minute;
    Int32 start2_int = start2.Hour * 60 + start2.Minute;
    Int32 end2_int = end2.Hour * 60 + end2.Minute;

    // add 24H if end is past midnight
    if (end1_int <= start1_int)
    {
        end1_int += 24 * 60;
    }

    if (end2_int <= start2_int)
    {
        end2_int += 24 * 60;
    }

    return (start1_int <= start2_int && end1_int >= end2_int);
}
```